# Outlook email rules no notification

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I made a rule to move emails from specfic person immediately to another folder. I noticed that I don't get notified when an email arrives to that folder. How can I make sure I get notification when emails arrived from that person? Now I get only notifications from emails in Inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an action "***display a Desktop Alert***" in your rule:

[image]